# Relative URL is relative to wrong absolute URL on web

Tags: httpd, website, web, url, html

#### Background

I am building a website. The files are:

```
/index.php
/pic.jpg
/dir/index.php
/dir/pic.jpg
```

As we know, people can visit my site's `dir/index.php` page using different URLs:

```
1. site.com/dir
2. site.com/dir/ 
3. site.com/dir/index.php
```

I have a link in `/dir/index.php`

```
<a target="_blank" href="pic.jpg">
```

which I want to relativly link to `/dir/pic.jpg`

#### The Problem

```
---------------------/-------------------------------                    
                             index.php
           pic.jpg
              ^
              |
        ------|-----/dir/------------------------
        |     |                                 |
        |     | 1                               |
        |     |                                 |
        |     |       2 or 3                    |
        | index.php ---------> pic.jpg          |
        -----------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------
```

The `href="pic.jpg"` leads people to different places when people visit the web via different urls.

People using url 1 get `/pic.jpg` , and others using url 2 or 3 get `/dir/pic.jpg`

The same problem goes with not just `<a>` but other HTML tags.

How can I write a relative URL in `/dir/index.php` that links to `/dir/pic.jpg` whatever URL visitors use?

I need to keep folder `dir` portable (I may change `dir`'s name, or use `dir` folder on another website, so it may have different path). We need a solution other than hardcoding `href="/dir/pic.jpg"`.

Comment: Why do not you just choose a different name for the `pic.jpg`?

Comment: site.com/dir should automatically redirect to site.com/dir/ when /dir is actually a directory and presto, your "problem" is solved

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have somehow not added a trailing slash to the first URL. If this directory actually exists on your server, then you would have had to intentionally misconfigure the web server to do this. You should undo that configuration, so that the server redirects the first example to the second example (the default).